# doctrine mongodb query builder projection with numbered indices

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm, akeneo

I need to limit the amount of data returned by a doctrine mongoDB query.
I could use `select` to project to simple fields or even simple embedded array fields like `normalizedData.ean`. That works perfectly.

However I have the necessary data in a form like the following:

```
"values" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59cbd73d83218bf7668b468d"),
        "attribute" : NumberLong("1"),
        "entity" : DBRef("pim_catalog_product", ObjectId("59148d2583218bf7508c1199"), "akeneo_pim"),
        "varchar" : "10011060"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59cbd73d83218bf7668b468e"),
        "attribute" : NumberLong("207"),
        "entity" : DBRef("pim_catalog_product", ObjectId("59148d2583218bf7508c1199"), "akeneo_pim"),
        "varchar" : "PRO70"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59cbd73d83218bf7668b468f"),
        "attribute" : NumberLong("110"),
        "entity" : DBRef("pim_catalog_product", ObjectId("59148d2583218bf7508c1199"), "akeneo_pim"),
        "option" : NumberLong("1890")
    }
]
```

The framework is Akeneo PIM btw.

So the problem here is, the `"values"` are not indexed through unique identifiers which I could use, but through numbered indices. I know the `"attribute"` number before hand, so I could query for that.

So what I am looking for is a doctrine mongo DB query builder that is capable of returning only those entities that actually contain values with attribute numbers 110 and 207, plus I only want to return the data within those values.

I have a working query builder that works with unique (string) indices:

```
$query = $productRepository->createQueryBuilder()
        ->hydrate(false)
        ->select(array('normalizedData.sku'))
        ->field('_id')->in($entityIds)
        ->limit($limit)
        ->skip($offset);
```

EDIT: now I found a way to query for those `"values"`, but I cannot project more than one attribute with this query:

```
$qb = $productRepository->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $qb
    ->hydrate(false)
    ->select(array('normalizedData.sku'))
    ->selectElemMatch(
        'values',
        $qb->expr()->field('attribute')->in(array(117, 110))->addAnd(
            $qb->expr()->field('locale')->in(array('it_IT', 'de_DE'))
        ))
    ->field('_id')->in($entityIds)
    ->field('values')->elemMatch($qb->expr()->field('attribute')->in(array(117, 110)))
    ->limit($limit)
    ->skip($offset);
```

What I am trying to get here are both attributes (117 and 110), but I only get one. Also, I get some results where neither attribute is present even though I imagined to have filtered out those with `->field('values')->elemMatch($qb->expr()->field('attribute')->in(array(117, 110)))`.

Obviously there are still some fundamentals I need to understand about mongoDB. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

How do I get only those entities that have either attribute 117 and/or 110 within their "values" collection, while also only getting those attributes data?

Note: The same attribute ID can be used multiple times with different languages. I would like to be able to limit the result to the languages specified as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the doctrine *Aggregation builder* ?
It might be a start of a solution, especially with the *unwind* function that can flatten your **values** an make the query easier to build.

https://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/aggregation-builder.html

Hope this would help you!